# When will Mono Runtime 3.2 be available in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mono, stable-release-updates

Does anyone know when Mono Runtime version 3.2 will be available with Ubuntu? The only stable released version I see is for MAC OS x. 3.2 has some things I need that 2.10 doesn't offer. Anyone know when it's coming or how I can get it to install?

Comment: Mono 3.2.8 and MonoDevelop 4.0 is their in ubuntu 14.04 LTS beta

Answer (score 1):

The version 3.2 just landed to Debian sid, from there, it should pass to testing, then to Ubuntu. I see lots of work there. You can check the [packages status in LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/mono). If you want to build from sources, you can check out the mono main page and build it yourself.